# How to handle large data from wcf service

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have wcf service, in one of method which returns a list.  Getting the data from oracle database, which is a large data(records in lakhs). This method when tested with wcf client works fine. When I consume the same service in silverlight application, I am getting timeout exceptions.. Pls suggest necessary steps to handle large data or avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

An application I worked on a few years ago had similar requirements. If my memory serves me correctly, we created some custom WCF behaviours that compressed/decompressed the dataset and transported it as binary data. You could also stream the data but this is a little more brittle in my opinion and requires more work on the client. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by holding data in object collection and use silverlight datagrid pagination, so   with proper coding you can show atleast 1000 records at time because as per my view user could not look lakhs of records by scroll down and scroll up. 
   If u don't want pagination then do the background threading, when user scroll up or scroll down data fetch as per index. Handle as much as data in coding level.

Above same thing i have done in my last project.